# AVD is not opened with API level 19

Tags: android, android-emulator

I installed API level 19 (V 4.4.2), and Created a AVD which has intelX86 ASI CPU. And tried to start up the AVD, and observed the following error message.

*Screenshot-1*

[image]

I googled and came to know there will be some problem to install Intelx 86 from SDK manager, and that should be present in "extras" category. But In my case I didn't see that image under extra, It shows under respective API(19) as displayed below. and displayed that Its installed correctly.

*Screenshot-2*

[image]
*Screenshot-3*

[image]
HAXM installed path:

[image]

Can somebody help me out.

Comment: 1. Your HAXM installed path image is actually of your x86 emulator directory. 2. The actual HAXM driver would be under Extras. 3. I'm guessing you are using an old version of the tools. If you open up the 'Tools' folder in Screenshot-3 what version of Android SDK Tools is installed. Currently its 24.4.1. Support Library is at version 23.1.1 - well above the 19.1 in your screenshot

Comment: I checked It shows 24.0.2 is SDK version

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your CPU supports virtualization technology from the BIOS menu, If you found enable it, then try  intelX86 type AVDs , If your processor doesn't support virtualization technology ,then try using armeabi type AVDs

Also check Intel HAXM is installed properly

For clarification refer the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Yep. HAXM is properly installed. Please find the screenshot above. But Can you tell me how to check Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. I'm using intel core i5 processor.

Comment: You can find a option to enable or disable virtualization in BIOS menu

Comment: I got it. Many thanks for input. Let me check and post you the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this same problem. It depends what you're trying to do when you want to test your code. There are two ways to run your code: on an "emulator" of an android device OR on the actually hardware of an android device. Here's how to go through the proper procedure of doing them both:

Using the Emulator - http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Using the Hardware - http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html